# Can't install an executable file

Tags: wine, games

I downloaded wine to play games like Wizard101 & Pirate101, and I was able run the executable files like those games. But I had problems with other stuff on my computer and had to do a factory reset.

Once I did, I couldn't install Wizard101. When I clicked on the thing that should install I got the message

> An error occurred while loading the archive

So, I did another factory reset and installed and configured Wine again. But I got the same message. Is there any way I can install the game or any executable file and run with Wine?

[image]

Comment: Did ***Wizard 101*** and ***Pirate 101*** used to run under wine and stopped running after factory reset? Or have they never run and factory reset is really just "noise"?

Comment: Have you installed the dependencies first ?? Like every game on wine needs special kind of libraries. Also instead using wine directly. Use playonlinux or crossover ..

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I used to play them before the 2 factory resets using wine. But now I can't even install them. Also, I have no idea what dependencies are.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find the problem and its solution. The problem was that it was automatically selected for the installation to be done with the archive manager. I just changed to open it with Wine and downloaded Wizard101.

Comment: Please could you clarify, because I am having a little trouble understanding exactly what you changed. Where was it "automatically selected for the installation to be done with the archive manager"? Was this a setting in wine or was it something you found by looking at the file properties? could you include a screenshot? When you say "changed to open it with wine", could you show or explain how you did this. Then you say that you downloaded the game again - but I was thinking you had fixed the configuration for the file type so you would be able to use the existing file, but no?

Comment: @Zanna it sounds like the installer was an .exe file that was set to default open in Archive Manager. Wine has a .exe loader app so you can double-click on a .exe file and have it open in Wine. Setting the .exe file properties so that the default app to use is the Wine .exe loader (I can't remember the name of that file, and I don't have Wine installed), then the program can be installed.